# How to create setup file(.Exe) with Database In Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c#, sql, database

I am new to C# . I am building application using C# windows forms and this application uses local MS SQL Express server database. 
for I example use this connection string to connect to "MyDB1" database :

```
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SqlServerName ;Initial Catalog=MyDB1;Integrated Security=True");
```

Until here everything is fine when I run my application in visual studio 2015 I can connect to database (The MyDB1 database is located in C:\DB ).

I want to create setup file (`.exe`) and to install it in other computers. Now the problem is with database because the connection string will not match with that computers as well as the SQL server name. I don't want the other users to change the connection string I just want to make it more convenient.

How to modify the above connection string to create `.exe` file with database that can be installed and work in other computers?

please help me. Thank you

Comment: put the connection string in your app.config.

Comment: If you don't have a full deployed Sql Server (or Sql Server Express) on the client premises you should take a look at the [LocalDB version of Sql Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx), deploy the required libraries and plan to change your connectionstring. (Starting from @DanielA.White 's comment)

Comment: @Daniel A. White . as I mentioned I do not want to put it in the app.config file .  I don't want the other users to change the connection string I just want to make it more convenient. any other idea?

Comment: there are plenty of options:  Use `localhost`, put the connection string in the app.config to allow the users to change it, Use a script during install to detect the name to use for the server, prompt the user for a name during the install, use an installer that automates this for you, use a SQL edition that installs in the app directory....  Ultimately the question is too broad, as there are way too many possibilities to discuss each option in detail.

Comment: @Serena i didn't see that posted in your question. you can encrypt the connection string.

Comment: @ Daniel A. White. Can you please show me how can I encrypt the connection string? Thank you